# How can I read a trained Tensorflow model file (.json) into Android app built with Capacitor (Vanilla JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, android, tensorflow, capacitor

### EDITED

I've built a cross-platform app with Capacitor, written in Vanilla JS. It uses the following code to load a trained Tensorflow model, a simple classifier NN built in Python.

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
....
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('./assets/models/model.json');
```

This works on the browser and I can use the model to make predictions. The model fails to load when deployed on Android.

In the Android Studio logcat I see the following error:

```
E  Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/assets/models/model.json
```

I also added these in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I know these are in the right location since there are other working permissions in the same place.

So far I've looked into:

- using the `@capacitor/filesystem` package but I'm not sure how it can be used to replicate the model-loading behaviour of `loadLayersModel`.
- using `file://`, `file:///`, `file:///andriod_asset`, `content://`, and `content://` in front of the path.
- using `Capacitor.convertFileSrc('./assets/models/model.json')`
- using different versions of the path (e.g. `src/assets/..`,)
- using `import {fetch as fetchPolyfill} from 'whatwg-fetch';` and `window.fetch = fetchPolyfill;`

..but I keep getting the error above, `Unable to open asset URL`.
When using `fetchPolyfill` and  `file:///andriod_asset/...` I get `Msg: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset`

I checked the Capacitor Doctor but seems fine for Android:

```
   Capacitor Doctor

Latest Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 5.5.1
  @capacitor/core: 5.5.1
  @capacitor/android: 5.5.1
  @capacitor/ios: 5.5.1

Installed Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 5.4.0
  @capacitor/ios: 5.4.0
  @capacitor/core: 5.4.1
  @capacitor/android: 5.4.0

[success] Android looking great! 
[error] Xcode is not installed
```

Here is an example app that makes the issue reproducible:
https://github.com/beetbox-music/cap_nn/tree/master

How can I replicate, in Android, the working behaviour of the app running on the browser?

### UPDATE:

Apparently, the issue has to do with the `vite.config.ts` file which is generated automatically by Capacitor.

As suggested by jcesarmobile:

- I added a folder to my `src` folder
- named it `public`
- added the line `publicDir: '../public'` in the `vite.config.ts`
- ran `npm run build` and `npx cap sync`

sadly this doesn't seem to have fixed the issue yet as I still don't see the model file in the android folders and see the same error.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  root: './src',
  publicDir: '../public',
  build: {
    outDir: '../dist',
    minify: false,
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
});
```

I also updated the app linked above to reflect these changes.
Let me know if I've interpreted your answer incorrectly.

Comment: It appears that the problem you're encountering when trying to load a TensorFlow model in a Capacitor app on Android is related to how Android manages asset URLs, especially when used within a webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discovered [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/7090), the problem was vite not copying the `src/assets` into `dist` folder.

Creating a separate `public` folder, putting the `assets` folder inside and configuring vite to use that public folder like `publicDir: “../public”` should fix the issue and then the vanilla code should work.

Comment: As written in the question's updated text, I attempted this unsuccessfully. Have I done anything wrong? I updated the app on GitHub to replicate the issue with the suggested changes if that helps.

Comment: The public folder should be outside the src folder, at the same level, that’s what I meant by separate folder.